# Error while installing Zeppelin notebook on EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, aws-glue

I have created an AWS Glue development endpoint (without specifying VPC and Subnet). Then with same endpoint I have tried to create Apache Zeppelin Notebook on EC2 instance but getting an error as CloudFormation rollback is complete.

AWS uses CloudFormation template to launch EC2 instance with same role as same as Zeppelin notebook. I observed it takes too much time to create EC2 instance (crossing timeout limit) then it has terminated immediately, with no role attached to EC2 instance.

I assigned role to Zeppelin notebook with below mentioned permissions:

- `AWSGlueServiceNotebookRole`
- `AmazonGleConsoleFullAccess`
- `iam:PassRole`
- `aws-glue*`

Used references:

- [Creating a Notebook Server Associated with a Development Endpoint - AWS Glue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/dev-endpoint-notebook-server-considerations.html)
- [Creating a Notebook Server Hosted on Amazon EC2 - AWS Glue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/console-ec2-notebook-create.html)

Can anyone guide me to how I could troubleshoot the issue? Steps or references help would be really appreciated.

Comment: can you post the error trace from cloudformation stack ?

Answer (score 0):

Skip cloudformation, launch a normal EC2 instance, and install zeppelin on it, then create an AMI from that instance. Use this new AMI for AWS Glue